# Spring Jdbc declarative transaction management within karaf

Tags: java, spring, osgi, spring-transactions, apache-karaf

I have project module, which is getting built as a osgi bundle (spring-dm).
Bundles are getting deployed in karaf container.
I have database interaction classees, which are developed using spring-jdbc.

I am not able to setup declarative transactions, can someone share experience / point me to resource where I can get more information.

**Frameworks with version**

Karaf : 2.2.9

Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few sites where declarative transactions are explained, those might help you.

[Spring JDBC in OSGi](http://www.aniketos.eu/content/spring-jdbc-osgi)

[Spring Declarative Transactions Example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/spring-declarative-transactions-example.html)

[Spring Declarative Transactions](http://simplespringtutorial.com/springDeclarativeTransactions.html)

[Spring Declarative Transaction Management](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/declarative_management.htm)